# Cyclic invariance of trace of fermions

Tags: operators, fermions, greens-functions, grassmann-numbers, trace

Consider the Green's function of fermion operators with imaginary time,
$$\mathcal{G}(\nu, \nu', \tau) = - \langle T_\tau c_{\nu}(\tau) c_{\nu'}^\dagger(0)\rangle\tag{1}$$
To show it satisfies the periodicity,
$$\mathcal{G}(\nu, \nu', \tau) = - \mathcal{G}(\nu, \nu', \tau+ \beta) \tag{2}$$
one needs to used the following identity, (see eq (71) and (72) on page 16 of http://folk.ntnu.no/johnof/green-2013.pdf)
$${\rm Tr}(ABC \ldots XY Z) = {\rm Tr}(ZAB \ldots   XY )\tag{71}$$

$$Tr(e^{-\beta H}c_{\nu'}^\dagger e^{H \tau} c_\nu e^{-H \tau} ) = Tr( e^{H \tau} c_\nu e^{-H \tau}  e^{-\beta H}c_{\nu'}^\dagger )\tag{3}$$
which is important for the appearance of the minus sign in equation (2). However, since $c_\nu$ and $c_\nu^\dagger$ are fermions, I doubt equation (3) is not correct. My question is whether (3) is indeed correct or not? If (3) is not correct, how can (2) hold?

Comment: equation (3) is an identity of the trace operator being cyclic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see why you might be  confused. If the trace were only over the spinor indices on a fermi field, $\psi_\alpha$ say, then there would be an additional minus sign. Here, however, the trace is over the entire many-body Hilbert space and the $c_\nu$'s are just like any other operator and so have a cyclic trace. This is what Ismasou's terse comment is saying.

Comment: Hello, I am still confused why if trace over the entire many-body Hilbert space, their don't have minus sign, is in this space fermion field don't have the anti-commutation property? Could you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

1. Consider the trace$^1$
   $$ {\rm Tr}_{\cal H}(A)~:=~\sum_{i} A^i{}_i \tag{A}$$
   of an operator $A:{\cal H}\to {\cal H}$
   with matrix elements
   $$A^i{}_j~:=~\langle i | A |j\rangle\tag{B}$$
   in some basis elements $|i\rangle$.
2. We assume that we can assign a Grassmann-parity $|i|$ to the elements $|i\rangle$ and a Grassmann-parity $|A|$ to the operator $A$. The Grassmann parity of the matrix elements $A^i{}_j$ are then
   $$|A^i{}_j| = |i| + |A| + |j|. \tag{C}$$
3. The cyclic trace property
   $$ {\rm Tr}(AB)~=~ \sum_{ij} A^i{}_j B^j{}_i~=~\sum_{ij} B^j{}_i A^i{}_j~=~{\rm Tr}(BA)\tag{D}$$
   holds for a class of infinite-dimensional matrices where the only non-zero matrix elements of the operators $A$ and $B$ are Grassmann-even:
   $$\begin{align} 
   A^i{}_j \text{ Grassmann-odd} \quad\Rightarrow& \quad A^i{}_j~=~0\cr
   B^i{}_j \text{ Grassmann-odd} \quad\Rightarrow& \quad B^i{}_j~=~0
   \end{align}\tag{E} $$
4. The links and references are implicitly assuming property (E) even for Grassmann-odd operators. This is readily fulfilled in practice, essentially because there are no Grassmann-odd numbers in Nature.

References:

1. G.D. Mahan, *Many-Particle Physics,* 1990; p. 134 + eq. (3.2.5).
2. G.D. Mahan, *Many-Particle Physics,* 2000; p. 110 + eq. (3.29).
3. A. Das, *Finite Temperature Field Theory,* 1997; p. 3.

--

$^1$ In contrast the [supertrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertrace)
$$ {\rm sTr}_{\cal H}(A)~:=~\sum_{i} (-1)^{|i|(1-|A|)} A^i{}_i \tag{F}$$
is super-cyclic
$$\begin{align} {\rm sTr}(AB)
~=~& \sum_{ij} (-1)^{|i|(1-|A|-|B|)}A^i{}_j B^j{}_i\cr
~=~&(-1)^{|A||B|}\sum_{ij} (-1)^{|j|(1-|A|-|B|)}B^j{}_i A^i{}_j\cr
~=~&(-1)^{|A||B|}{\rm sTr}(BA).
\end{align}\tag{G}$$

Comment: Why $A^i_{  \ \  j}=0$ if it’s Grassmann-old? Sorry for this stupid question! I am new for this.

Comment: I updated the answer.