# Grassmann property of Fermion field in Hilbert space and spinor space

Tags: hilbert-space, fermions, spinors, grassmann-numbers, trace

If we consider the trace of two fermion field ($\psi_A \ \psi_B$), and using the cyclic property of trace (which has Grassmann property in general I thought).
$$
\text{Tr}(\psi_A \ \psi_B)=(-)\text{Tr}(\psi_B \ \psi_A).
$$
I am told that(not directly, I deduced, maybe wrong):

(1) if fermion field in spinor space, above equation have a minus sign;

(2) if fermion field in many-body Hilbert space, above equation don't have minus sign.

Why? Is in Hilbert space the anti-commutation property don't satisfy?

Here is how I deduce above two cases:

1. I am learning "Finite Temperature Field Theory" by Ashok Das, on page 3, the book derived the Kubo-Martin-Schwinger (KMS) relation;
   $$
   \begin{aligned}
   \left\langle A_H(t) B_H\left(t^{\prime}\right)\right\rangle_\beta &=Z^{-1}(\beta) \operatorname{Tr} \rho(\beta) A_H(t) B_H\left(t^{\prime}\right) \\
   &=Z^{-1}(\beta) \operatorname{Tr} e^{-\beta \mathcal{H}} A_H(t) B_H\left(t^{\prime}\right) \\
   &=Z^{-1}(\beta) \operatorname{Tr} \mathrm{e}^{-\beta \mathcal{H}} A_H(t) \mathrm{e}^{\beta \mathcal{H}} \mathrm{e}^{-\beta \mathcal{H}} B_H\left(t^{\prime}\right) \\
   &{\color{blue}=}Z^{-1}(\beta) \operatorname{Tr} A_H(t+i \beta) \mathrm{e}^{-\beta \mathcal{H}} B_H\left(t^{\prime}\right) \\
   &{\color{blue}=}Z^{-1}(\beta) \operatorname{Tr} \mathrm{e}^{-\beta \mathcal{H}} B_H\left(t^{\prime}\right) A_H(t+i \beta) \\
   &=\left\langle B_H\left(t^{\prime}\right) A_H(t+i \beta)\right\rangle_\beta
   \end{aligned}
   $$
   And I am troubled for the step where I use "blue" color to mark. That step use the cyclic property of trace. And the book further said: "this relation holds independent of Grassmann parities of the operator $A$ and $B$, namely, for both bosons as well as fermionic operators."
2. Then I searched this question inside Physics SE, and I find this [similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/533078/cyclic-invariance-of-trace-of-fermions). You can check this question and the answer by "mike stone".

That's how I deduce my argument.

Comment: Reference to statements? Which pages?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/533078/2451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider gamma matrices. We have $\gamma^1 \gamma^2 = -\gamma^2\gamma^1$ but the cyclic property of the trace  is *still true*:  ${\rm tr}\{\gamma^1 \gamma^2\}= {\rm tr}\{\gamma^2 \gamma^1\}$.  Of course this tells us that ${\rm tr}\{\gamma^1 \gamma^2\}= -{\rm tr}\{\gamma^1 \gamma^2\}$, so in this case we must have${\rm tr}\{\gamma^1 \gamma^2\}=0$.

Your example is more complicated, but the same cyclic property holds.